# How to determine a param is necessary or not based on another param?

Tags: typescript

I have a function named useFunc which use another function named func as its first parameter, but right now I don't known if func needs parameters or not, so if func needs parameter, the second parameter of useFunc is necessary, otherwise not.

```
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithParam, param: IParamOfFunc)
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithoutParam)
```

So how to define useFunc's type ?

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, you can have multiple function definitions but with only one implementation. You'd format it like so for your use-case:

```js
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithParam, param: IParamOfFunc)
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithoutParam)
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithParam | IFuncWithoutParam, param: IParamOfFunc) {
  if(func.param != undefined) {
    // with func.param being the present or not-present parameter,
    // and using != undefined because it could be either undefined or null.

    // ...
  } else { // func instanceof IFuncWithoutParam
    // ...
  }
}
```

*Note: If it is a class, you can use `instanceof IFuncWithParam` instead.*

---

Alternatively, you could just take the "highest level" object and do the following by using `Object.assign`:

```js
function useFunc(func: IFuncWithoutParam)

const foo: IFuncWithParam;
const fooParam: IParamOfFunc;

useFunc(Object.assign(foo, { param: fooParam }) as IFuncWithoutParam);
```

Comment: thx, but I don't think "func instanceof IFuncWithParam" works, because IFuncWithParam is a type instead of value,

Comment: If `IFuncWithParam` is a type then you'll have to do some other check there, like `if(func.param != undefined) // therefore it is an IFuncWithParam`. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: thx a lot, still I have two questions:

What is the use of third definition? 
What if I have more than one param to determine rather than one? It seems I have to overload a lot of times

Comment: (1) The last definition is the implementation. The first two are what everything else sees; i.e. the ways you can *use* the function, whereas the last is the underlying function that is flexible enough to take any of the overloaded parameters. (2) You can keep adding overloaded functions, or you can figure out a new way to do the function entirely. For instance, if they are all variants of the same base object, why not just take the base object? Or if they all take the extra parameters, why not do something like I added in the second part of my answer?